# Create Spring boot web service with out using main method

Tags: java, spring

How can i create web service using spring boot without creating main method (what i mean is to create maven web application not maven java application from netbeans) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short for maven (as you seem to use that) follow these steps. You will need to implement servlet initializer, like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

you can leave main method if you wish.

Change packaging from jar to war in pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Finally add this dependency (pom.xml):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have to leave main method in case i try to remove it i get this exception         
`Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project Login-WS: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class`                        is there any way to remove it?

Comment: If you DON'T want the benefits of both be able to run with embedded container (e.g. from your IDE) AND deploying to a standalone application container (tomcat) then you simply remove 'spring-boot-maven-plugin' and the main method. When you package your module in this way you can deploy it to the standalone application container only.